# nodejs - Unexpected behevior from consecutive execSync functions

Tags: node.js, docker

I have the following running in nodejs on my Ubuntu 16. to handle the termination of the nodejs program:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    process.exit(); // On ctrl + C, exit this process.
});

// catches the exit(). On exit, execute our handler function.
process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null, { exit: true }));

async function exitHandler(options, exitCode) {

    try {
        await execSync("docker kill $(docker ps -q -a)");
    } catch (err) {
        errOut(err);
    }
    try {
        await execSync("docker rm $(docker ps -q -a)");
    } catch (err) {
        errOut(err);
    }
    stdOut("\nExiting the process..");
}
```

The problem is if the first `await execSync` executes gracefully, The next `await execSync` will not execute. But weirdly if first `execSync` crashes and ends up in errors, the second one will execute. I want them both to execute one after another at any situation. I have no idea how to crack this down.

Comment: could you share the error trace?

Comment: It is a controlled error that says the container is already not running, so can't be killed. `Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 8f5d884d9883: Container 8f5d884d9883... is not running`

Comment: It's not possible to kill a not running container, change the first `execSync` to `docker kill $(docker ps -q)`

Comment: That's a good suggestion. But I may have explained the problem bad, the real problem here is that the nodejs does not behave the way i think try {`await execSync`}... should behave. Some processes might be alive, i wanna kill them first, as you mentioned, without the `-a`. 

But if there is no error, MY NEXT INSTRUCTION WILL NOT EXECUTE.

Comment: May be you have several containers and the command takes some time to be completly excuted

Comment: in nodejs, using `await execSync(..)` instruction instead of `exec(..)` will force the current process to wait for the execution to end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179800/discussion-between-andolsi-zied-and-makan-tayebi).

Answer (score 1):

The command `docker ps -q -a` returns all containers' id, so if there some not running container, the command `docker kill` will return error.

To fix this, change the first execSync to `docker kill $(docker ps -q)`.